# Creating debug builds of Ocaml code with Jbuilder

Tags: ocaml, ocamldebug, ocaml-dune

I have been reading the tutorials for the Ocaml language and for Jbuilder. The official tutorial indicates that [one must compile Ocaml code using the '-g' flag](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/debug.html#Launching-the-debugger) with ocamlc in order to then run ocamldebug.

I cannot find any mention of debug builds on the Jbuilder documentation. The only section that seems close is https://jbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jbuild.html#ocaml-flags. However, even if I add '-g' as a compilation flag..

```
(executable
 ((name [REDACTED])
  (public_name [REDACTED])
  (libraries ([REDACTED]))
  (flags (:standard -w -9+27-30-32-40@8
                    -safe-string
                    -linkall
                    -g))
  (modules ([REDACTED]))))
```

..I still don't seem to get a debug binary:

```
$ ocamldebug [REDACTED] 
    OCaml Debugger version 4.04.2

(ocd) r
Loading program... [REDACTED] is not a bytecode file.
```

Am I doing something wrong? If not, what is the recommended way to produce debug builds from jbuilder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ocamldebug` only works with bytecode builds. You're producing native code. To create a bytecode build, you can invoke `jbuilder` using `prog.bc` instead of `prog.exe`.

Note that this might not be what you're after: you can also debug native programs using plain old `gdb`, but you'll need to be a bit familiar with the runtime.

Comment: After reading the documentation, I added this to the jbuild file:

    (modes      (byte))

After this, .bc files were produced and ocamldebug seemed to work. 

Is this the right method to produce bytecode or is there a better way?

Comment: I think that `(modes (bytes))` only affects what is built by default, but that you can always run `jbuild build prog.bc`.